# Why class is giving error when I am creating it using a header and a cpp file of same name of the class

Tags: c++, class

I have created a class named Cat. When I am trying to access the Cat class then it shows following error.

```
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
F:\Classes\Classes.o:Classes.cpp|| undefined reference to 'Cat::Cat()'|
F:\Classes\Classes.o:Classes.cpp|| undefined reference to 'Cat::speak()'|
F:\Classes\Classes.o:Classes.cpp|| undefined reference to 'Cat::~Cat()'|
F:\Classes\Classes.o:Classes.cpp|| undefined reference to 'Cat::~Cat()'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Here are my codes:

For Classes.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Cat.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello"<<endl;
    Cat cat1;
    cat1.speak();
    cout<<"Program Ended..."<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For Cat.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Cat.h"
using namespace std;
Cat::Cat()
{
    cout<<"Cat created.."<<endl;
    color = 'R';
}
Cat::~Cat()
{
    cout<<"Cat Destroyed.."<<endl;
}
void Cat::speak()
{
    if(color == 'R')
        cout<<"I am a red Cat....."<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"I am a Cat.....------"<<endl;
}
```

For Cat.h

```
#ifndef CAT_H_INCLUDED
#define CAT_H_INCLUDED
class Cat
{
    public:
        void speak();
        char color;
        Cat();
        ~Cat();
    protected:
    private:
};
#endif // CAT_H_INCLUDED
```

One thing I should mention. All these files are in same folder and I am using CodeBlocks.

Comment: It looks like to forgot to include Cat.cpp in your build.

Comment: Grt!! It's Working now. But why should I include the Cat.cpp file while I already included the header file where the class is defined? @RSahu

Comment: The member functions of `Cat` are only declared in the .h file. They are defined in the .cpp file. The compiler does not automatically pickup the implementation from the .cpp file when the .h file is `#include`d in another file.

Comment: Ah code blocks; would of never been able to answer that since I use MSVS. MSVS automatically creates *.obj files during compilation if all the correct headers are included properly and all the correct libraries are linked properly.

Answer (score 2):

"undefined reference to" is often received when you forget to link a library which contains the definition to the function you are using in your code. Your situation is similar.
So either 
- you create a separate library for your "Cat" code and link to your client code (Class.cpp) OR
- Compile is similar fashion as below line
g++ Classes.cpp Cat.cpp -o Cat